# How to download list of files from Parse

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I'm trying to download files that I've uploaded to Parse core. (I'm using Parse Unity SDK)

I have a Parse table call "DLC" to store all the downloadable files.
But now I have no ideas how to download it from the application itself.

These are my codes, I'm stucked

```
void GetParseFiles()
    {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("DLC");
        query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsCompleted)
            {
                IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;

                int count = 0;
                foreach(ParseObject obj in results)
                {
                    ParseFile parseFile = obj.Get<ParseFile>("LevelFiles");
                    WWW request = new WWW(parseFile.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                // what should I do in order to get the content of the file?
                }

                Debug.Log(count);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope someone can tell me how can I do it?
What am I trying to achieve is I would like to store some data files (in .txt or .xml format) to Parse server then other users will be getting the data files from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here..

I shouldn't use ContinueWith if I need to put a yield statement in the function block.

https://parse.com/questions/unity-after-i-uploaded-a-jpeg-as-a-parsefile-using-the-data-browser-how-can-i-retrieve-and-display-it-from-unity-with-c-code